# how to write create table date query in phpmyadmin which store by default current date if date not given?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a table (**phpMyAdmin**) by using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE login_detail(
     Id int(11) primary key auto_increment, 
     userName varchar(100) not null,
     userPassword varchar(100) not null, 
     created_at Date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```

but it showing error at `CURRENT_DATE`. Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not supported.

The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

you just use current time stamp .below code i tested in phpmyadmin.it working fine

```
CREATE TABLE login_detail(Id int(11) primary key auto_increment, userName      varchar(100) not null,userPassword varchar(100) not null, created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_detail` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `userPassword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `login_detail` (`Id`, `userName`, `userPassword`) VALUES
(1, 'aaa', 'bbb'),
(2, 'aaa', 'bbb');
```

To get the date and-or time in the format you want use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT `Id`, `userName`, `userPassword`, DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%e %b %Y') AS `created_at_date`, DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%H:%i:%s') AS `created_at_time`  FROM `login_detail`;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea673/1